# What on earth is this that came out of my sink's drain?

Tags: drainage, blockage

Our kitchen sink was draining really slowly so I went to town with the plunger. When it finally unblocked I went outside to where the waste drains and found all of this!

[image: Yuck]

Yuck!

Can anyone tell me what they think it is?

Our utilities are on the other side of the kitchen to the outside drain, so our washing machine, dish washer and sink all drain via a long pipe under the floor.

I presume that this gunk has just been collecting in that pipe over the years, and I've finally got it to move.

Any thoughts on what the likely cause is and if there's anything I should be doing to prevent the build up? (I have no plans to lift the floor to give that pipe more of an angle!)

Thanks

Comment: Eww. Trigger warning, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fat blobs.

Stop letting fats/oils go down the drain.

A search should have a few pictures of fat blobs in sewers.  I think there was a story a few years ago about them cleaning fat blobs from London sewers.

Comment: **Fatberg** was the term popularized by the London sewers issues, as I recall it.

Comment: Yep.  You should be storing used kitchen fats in a container that you then throw in the solid refuse.  We keep a jar on the counter for draining stuff like bacon fat.  Though sometimes we keep it for future cooking purposes—but you only need so much bacon fat.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did initially think this too (living in London myself, very aware of the fatbergs lurking under my feet!), but dismissed it because we very rarely cook fatty foods. However as Crip said, it's not just fat, it's oil too, and we use a fair amount of olive oil (which I guess is just fat by a different name). Always assumed that because it's going down the sink with copious amounts of washing up liquid it would be fine, but live and learn. Thanks all